# JavaScript cloning a "class" instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, clone, extend

I have a class that goes like this:

```
function Element(){
    this.changes = {};
}
```

Now I have an instance of this "Class" like so, `el = new Element()`. These instances are stored in an array, like `elements.push(el)`.

This array of elements is now stored in an object, which is then pushed in an array, `states`.

Now there are cases where I need a copy of one of the elements, so I would need to do something like, `var cloned = $.extend(true, {}, states[0])`. Here I assumed that we are cloning the first state.

The problem now is that what I get, the `state[1].elements[0]` is still pointing to the original instance. Thus any changes I am making to the cloned object, are changing the original too.

It's frustrating to be stuck on such a trivial problem...

Here is a fiddle I created to test it out:
http://jsfiddle.net/E6wLW/

Comment: I don't seem to be able to replicate this, have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uU5xU/).

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: I just added a link to a jsfiddle snippet

Comment: Also, I have made some more edits to the problem

Comment: What you want to do is called a "deep copy" operation.  One very simple thing that might work, depending on your object contents and performance needs, is to JSON encode an object and then decode it again.

Comment: The correct solution is to re-design your algorithms to remove the need for deep copying. Deep copying is a) a nightmare to get right, b) computationally expensive, c) creates logic that relies on everything being deep copied. Deep copying is a difficult problem to solve and should simply be avoided by using shallow copies instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) is only cloning plain objects. If the object has a constructor then it is not cloned, but just copied.

From the [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) source:

```
if ( jQuery.isPlainObject(copy) /* ... */) {
  // do the recursive $.extend call and clone the object                
} else if ( copy !== undefined ) {
  target[ name ] = copy;
  // ^^^^^ just copy
}
```

So [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) will call [`isPlainObject(el)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isPlainObject/) which will return false, because `el` has an constructor and instead of cloning the `el` is copied. So `states[1].elements[0]` is the same object as `states[0].elements[0]` because it was not cloned.

If we modify your example from:

```
function Element(){
  this.changes = {};
}
var el = new Element();    // $.isPlainObject(el); <- false
// ...
```

into:

```
var el = { changes: {} };  // $.isPlainObject(el); <- true
// ...
```

It will clone the `el` properly. See it **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/ukTvm/)**.

Comment: So basically jQuery's extend method is silly.

Comment: @Raynos `$.extend()` cannot fully supporting objects with constructors because it don't know what paremeters to use.

Comment: what parameters to use is irrelevant. All they need to do is copy the objects properties over one for one. That's pretty easy to do.

Comment: @Raynos That is not all you need to do because you have all the properties of the object, but the prototype is not correct and it is far from being a "clone". Or am I missing something :)?

Comment: @Raynos http://stackoverflow.com/a/728694/1011582 contains some info about problems when trying to clone objects that are not plain

Comment: [clone](https://gist.github.com/1452024). Ignoring the ton of edge cases and black magic you have to do, the core of the clone function is really easy. The main problem areas are host objects and native objects with internal magic. Oh and avoiding circular references in deep copies.

Comment: @Raynos That looks nice, but I don't think that `$.extend()` should implement something like that unless it can do all the black magic to support it fully :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#clone to clone object, like:

```
var cloned = _.clone(states[0]);
```

Comment: This won't work. Read the link you posted: `Any nested objects or arrays will be copied by reference, not duplicated.`